# Is there any other way to minimize my Javascript long if condiftion to check rows and cols of a suduko game?

Tags: javascript

I've been practicing javascript, and made a suduko game. I push() some numbers inside an array.

```
var sudukoNmb = [1,2,3,3,2,1,2,1,3]
```

and I have this condition to read the numbers by rows and by columns, but I think its not the proper way.

```
if(sudukoNmb[0] === sudukoNmb[1] || sudukoNmb[0] === sudukoNmb[2] || sudukoNmb[1] === sudukoNmb[2] ||
  sudukoNmb[0] === sudukoNmb[3] || sudukoNmb[0] === sudukoNmb[6] || sudukoNmb[3] === sudukoNmb[6] ||
  sudukoNmb[1] === sudukoNmb[4] || sudukoNmb[1] === sudukoNmb[7] || sudukoNmb[4] === sudukoNmb[7] ||
  sudukoNmb[3] === sudukoNmb[4] || sudukoNmb[3] === sudukoNmb[5] || sudukoNmb[4] === sudukoNmb[5] ||
  sudukoNmb[6] === sudukoNmb[7] || sudukoNmb[6] === sudukoNmb[8] || sudukoNmb[7] === sudukoNmb[8] ||
  sudukoNmb[2] === sudukoNmb[5] || sudukoNmb[2] === sudukoNmb[8] || sudukoNmb[5] === sudukoNmb[8]) {
  console.log('error')
} else {
  console.log('correct')
}
```

Is there any other way to minimize this condition?

**Note:** these numbers are actually come from rows and columns indices of a 2D array (3x3) mapped in a 1D array. (sudukoNmb[3] is for first cell of second row and so on...)

Comment: Yes with a loop.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yes I've been trying it with a loop. But i'm not getting it, since I also have 0==1; 0==2; 0==3 and 0==6.

Comment: @EmmanR could you explain your logic about the condition in your if()

Comment: @xianshenglu see my post explanation to find the logic behind those number

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek ok, but the problem is that the array indices don't have a simple relation to be used in the loop. for more details, please see my post below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its relatively hard to understand the logic behind your condition, but i found that it is comparing rows and columns of a 2D array (3x3) stored in a 1D array (total 9 elements).

So the array contains following elements:

```
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
```

and we must check every row or column such that they don't have same values in each horizontal or vertical line. For example:

- the first row is:  0,1,2 => we shall check: 0,1 / 0,2 / 1,2
- the second row is: 3,4,5 => we shall check: 3,4 / 3,5 / 4,5
- the third row is:  6,7,8 => we shall check: 6,7 / 6,8 / 7,8

so the formula for rows is: `check i,(i+1) / i,(i+2) / (i+1),(i+2)`

and

- the first column is: 0, 3, 6 => we shall check: 0,3 / 0,6 / 3,6
- the second column is: 1, 4, 7 => we shall check: 1,4 / 1,7 / 4,7
- the third column is: 2, 5, 8 => we shall check: 2,5 / 2,8 / 5,8

so the formula for rows is: `check i,(i+3) / i,(i+2*3) / (i+3),(i+2*3)`

we can merge both formulas to one more general:

```
check i,(i+n) / i,(i+2*n) / (i+n),(i+2*n)
```

where n is 1 for rows and is 3 for columns.

the following code can check the values in every column or row:

```js
var sudukoNmb = [1,2,3, 4,5,6, 7,5,9];

function checkLine(a, i, n) //a:array, i: first cell index, n: offset to get next cell in row or column
{
 return (a[i]===a[i+n] || a[i]===a[i+2*n] || a[i+n]===a[i+2*n]);
}

var msg = "OK";

for(var j=0; j<2; j++)
{
  //if (checkLine(sudukoNmb, j, 3)) {msg="Error"; break;} //to check columns
  //if (checkLine(sudukoNmb, j*3, 1)) {msg="Error"; break;} //to check rows
  if (checkLine(sudukoNmb, j, 3) || checkLine(sudukoNmb, j*3, 1))
    {msg = "Error"; break;}
}

console.log("Check result is: " + msg);
```

Comment: This is a superb answer because it clearly explains the thinking needed to write the solution. I'd personally recommend removing the `script` tags from the code because there's no indication by the OP that this runs inside an HTML

Comment: @slebetman thanks for your comment. actually, that `script` tag was due to code snippet html panel of stackoverflow... anyway, i move the code to js panel to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

> Try This

```
var sudukoNmb = [1,2,3,3,2,1,2,1,3],
allow  = [[1,2,3,6], [2,4,7], [5,8], [6,4,5], [7,5], [8], [7,8], [8]];
var f = 0;
allow.forEach(function(v,i){
    v.forEach(function(vv){
        if(sudukoNmb[i] == sudukoNmb[vv]) f=1;
    })
})
if(f) console.log('error')
else console.log('correct')
```

Answer (score 0):

The nine values of a "sudoku box" are supposed to be unique, so it could be possible to take advantage of the `Set` class of ES6, it stores unique values.

```
var sudukoNmb = [1,2,3,3,2,1,2,1,3]

if (new Set(sudukoNmb).size === 9) { // Set instance has [1,2,3] only
    console.log('correct')
} else {
    console.log('error')
}
```

Comment: This is not what OP wants to check. your code will return false when every 2 cells have the same value, but the OP want to compare cells only in rows and columns! for example it must return correct for `sudukoNmb = [1,2,3, 4,5,6, 3,8,9]` as the repetitive 3's are not in same row or column, but your code returns error!

Comment: Emman R: "I've been practicing javascript, and made a suduko game", "these numbers are actually come from rows and columns indices of a 2D array (3x3) mapped in a 1D array", Leon Plata: "The nine values of a 'sudoku box' are supposed to be unique"

Comment: Considering the previous statements it's wrong to have a duplicated number in the array so it's ok to return error for `sudukoNmb = [1,2,3, 4,5,6, 3,8,9]` @S.Serp

Comment: I see, but the long `if`provided in the original question checks only rows and cols separately, not all cross cells (as it could be check via 2 simple nested loops). as i remember in real large sudoko games (9x9 elements divided to 3x3 areas each itself a 3x3 table), we have to check overall long rows and cols individually. anyway, good to point the `Set` class.